# VBA code required to create macro in excel to extract sentenses under a name from pdf

Tags: excel, vba

Attempting to extract text lines from pdf to excel.

I'm currently working with a large number of pdf files containing standardized information for certain headers. Each file has the same list of headers. I've put together some code that pulls in each sentence from the pdf files under each header and includes them together in a single excel spreadsheet.

The problem here is the rows/sentences under one of the header in pdf may vary for example under header name "biography" in one pdf there may be 2 sentences and in another there may be 4 sentences . What I would like is to copy all the sentences under the "biography" irrespective of no.of sentences it have and move to next header.

Comment: Please show us the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can't operate with PDF from Excel directly - only via some other application.
This can be MS Word.
How I did it.
a) Create an application object in Excel.

```
 Dim wApp As Object' declare an object variable
    Dim wDoc As New Word.Document  'declare a wod=rd document variable
    Set wApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")'set the object as Word application
```

b) Open PDF by Word

```
wApp.Documents.Open Filename:="your PDF file name", ReadOnly:=True
Set wDoc = wApp.ActiveDocument
```

c) Act with this document

```
 With wApp
        With .wDoc 
    'Some actions using [MS Word Object model][1] - in Your case you assign value of some Word object to a variable
    
        End with
    End With
```